# How did the first computer model display text?

Tags: computer-architecture, history

I have a question ive not been able to explain, and I still cant find the answer looking through computer history. I want to know how the first letters were programmed into the first computer.

Let me explain more..

So when i research computer history they discuss the machines and how they work and when dos was invented, and I learned about how they used lightbulbs for an 8 bit calculator.. but then it just kind of skips my question in the timeline of it all and just say the next generation uses dos!

Well i understand how dos works.. but how to you program what each letter looks like... How did the computer know how to draw a T on the screen. Or a 1 or a 0? How did they saughter a circuit board and somehow get text to appear on a screen in characters we understand.. that blows my mind can anybody help?

Comment: Instead of sending electrical signals to light the right lightbulbs, it sends electrical signals to tell the monitor to light up certain pixels. I'm not sure there's much more to say, without delving into the electrical engineering details, which are off-topic, here. This question might be more appropriate for [retrocomputing.se].

Comment: Thank you david richerby that makes sense actually. In simple terms. I think i can fill in the gaps from here. And my apologies for the wrong topic. I dont ask questions often I usually answer them.

Comment: Take a look at the linked questions; that should provide more information and might help clear things up.  If you're still confused, feel free to ask a new, more specific question based on what you've learned.  And welcome to the site!